# Linking splitmuxsrc element in GStreamer using Python

Tags: gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

Hello I am trying to use following GStreamer pipeline in Python3.6

```
splitmuxsrc location=clip000*.mp4 ! video/x-h264,alignment=au ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

The pipeline itself is working, however when I translate it into python it gives following error:

**Error: gst-stream-error-quark: Internal data stream error. (1), gstsplitmuxsrc.c(598): gst_splitmux_pad_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSplitMuxSrc:muxsrc:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)**

It appears that linking ***splitmuxsrc*** to ***h264parse*** does not do anything.

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject

# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(None)

# Create GStreamer pipeline
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

# Create elements
muxsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("splitmuxsrc", "muxsrc")
h264parse = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse", "h264parse")
avdec_h264 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("avdec_h264", "avdec_h264")
videoconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "videoconvert")
xvimagesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("xvimagesink", "xvimagesink")

# Add elements to the pipeline
pipeline.add(muxsrc)
pipeline.add(h264parse)
pipeline.add(avdec_h264)
pipeline.add(videoconvert)
pipeline.add(xvimagesink)

# Link elements
muxsrc.link(h264parse)
h264parse.link(avdec_h264)
avdec_h264.link(videoconvert)
videoconvert.link(xvimagesink)

# Set properties if needed
muxsrc.set_property("location", "clip000*.mp4")

# Set up the main loop
loop = GObject.MainLoop()


# Bus callback function
def bus_callback(bus, message, loop):
    t = message.type
    if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End of Stream")
        loop.quit()
    elif t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        print("Error: {}, {}".format(err, debug))
        loop.quit()
    return True


# Create and set up the bus
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect("message", bus_callback, loop)

# Start the pipeline
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

# Run the main loop
try:
    loop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Stop the pipeline
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

I have been trying to get and link ***src*** of ***splitmuxsrc*** with ***sink*** of ***h264parse*** however it appears that ***splitmuxsrc*** does not have static src pad. And also when I try to get request pads of ***splitmuxsrc*** (video) I get none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this issue I have managed to get this running. It appears that `src` pad for `splitmuxsrc` is only available once pipeline starts running and element loads clips. You need to add handler for this event like this `muxsrc.connect('pad-added', self.on_pad_added, h264parse)` and then in handler link newly added `src` pad to the rest of the pipeline, in my case to sink of `h264parse` element that I have passed as `data` for the handler.

```
# on pad added handler
def on_pad_added(element, pad, data):
    pad.link(data.get_static_sink())
```